# How to display multiple location in a google map by retrieving the data from google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-sheets

I coded the google map to display multiple in map with clickable icon.

The code is as follows

```
<html>
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
  .container{width: auto; height: auto; }
  .clear{clear: both;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
['abc', -31.987717, 115.814430, 'our place','image path', 'What is the work'],
['abc',-32.240765, 115.904158 , 'our place','image path', 'What is the work'],

    ];
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.65,116.688),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
        myOptions);
    setMarkers(map,locations)
  }
  function setMarkers(map,locations){
      var marker, i
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
 {  
 var loan = locations[i][0]
 var lat = locations[i][1]
 var long = locations[i][2]
 var add =  locations[i][3]
 var image =  locations[i][4]
 latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset  
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
        var content = "<div class='container'>" + '<div style="float:left;">' +'<h2> Heading </h2>' + add +'</div>'+ '<div style="float:right;">' +"<img src='" + image +"'/></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"    
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
  var activeWindow;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
            //Close active window if exists 
            if(activeWindow != null)
              activeWindow.close(); 
            //Open new window 
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.open(map,marker); 
            //Store new window in global variable 
              activeWindow = infowindow; 
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
  }
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I want to fetch the Heading text, co-ordinate, image path etc from google spreadsheet.

I have tried this code

```
    <html>
        <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 </head>
   <body>
    <script>
            //https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g/pubhtml
            var cell1= "a1";
            var cell2= "b1";
            var cell3= "c1";
            var cell4= "d1";
$.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range="+cell1+"&b6&output=csv").done(function(result1){
document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = result1;
});
$.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range="+cell2+"&b6&output=csv").done(function(result2){
document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = result2;
                });
$.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range="+cell3+"&b6&output=csv").done(function(result3){
document.getElementById("display3").innerHTML = result3;
});
$.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range="+cell4+"&b6&output=csv").done(function(result4){
 document.getElementById("display4").innerHTML = result4;
                });
 </script>
    <div id="display1"></div>
    <div id="display2"></div>
    <div id="display3"></div>
    <div id="display4"></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

I simply wish to know how to call varible result1, result2, result3, result4 value in **location** array.

Anyone's help appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Declare `locations` as a global variable, create a string in the required format from the spreadsheet data and use `locations.push(string)`.  Run this before rendering the map.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle link :)

Comment: you can copy and paste the above code to a html file and run in browser @ Gourav Makhija..

Comment: can you please go the script @sideroxylon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wait for the return of ajax before make the map.

here a working example for one marker:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }
          .container{width: auto; height: auto; }
          .clear{clear: both;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

    var locations = [];
    $( document ).ready(initialize())

          function initialize() {
              var cell1 = "a1";
              var cell2 = "b1";
              var cell3 = "c1";
              var cell4 = "d1";
              $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell1 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result1) {
                $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell2 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result2) {
                  $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell3 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result3) {
                    $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell4 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result4) {
                      console.log("here");
                      locations.push(result1 + ', ' + result2 + ', ' + result3 + ', ' + result4); 
                      makeMap();
                    });
                  });
                });
              });

          }

          function makeMap() {
            var myOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.65,116.688),
              zoom: 5,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
                myOptions);
            setMarkers(map,locations)

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          }
          function setMarkers(map,locations){
              var marker, i
                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
                 {  
                 console.log(locations);
                 var res = locations[0].split(" ");
                 console.log(res);
                 var loan =   res[0]
                 var lat = -31.987717
                 var long = 115.814430
                 var add =  res[3] + res[4] + res[5]
                 var image =  res[6]
                 console.log(add)
                 console.log(image)
                 latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                          map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset  
                        });
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
                        var content = "<div class='container'>" + '<div style="float:left;">' +'<h2> Heading </h2>' + add +'</div>'+ '<div style="float:right;">' +"<img src='" + image +"'/></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"    
                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
                  var activeWindow;
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                        return function() {
                            //Close active window if exists 
                            if(activeWindow != null)
                              activeWindow.close(); 
                            //Open new window 
                              infowindow.setContent(content);
                              infowindow.open(map,marker); 
                            //Store new window in global variable 
                              activeWindow = infowindow; 
                        };
                    })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
                  }
          }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="">
      <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note: This is not clean code. When one request is inside the other(like the initialize function) we named as Pyramid of Doom. You can use [q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for more clean code.

Comment: Can you post a Clean working code for me @Tom Karachristos .... The above code is not working for me

Comment: I added a full working example for one marker. Tell me if you have a question.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are suggesting you run your AJAX requests in series which in practice there is zero reason to do, so I'll offer a small variation. I've also tried to reduce code replication.

```
var locations = []; //global variable array

$(document).ready(function() {
    var cells = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"];
  var url_start = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=";
  var url_end = "&b6&output=csv";

  // for each of our cells
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    // perform the ajax call
    $.ajax(url_start + cells[i] + url_end).done(function(result){
      // once we get our reply, store it
        locations.push(result);
      // was this the last reply?
      if(locations.length == 4){
          // then add our locations!
          addToMap();
      }
    });
  }
});

function addToMap() {
  //here's the result of your ajax requests to the spreadsheet.  You can use them in your map function.
  $('#locations').html('[' + locations.join(", ") + ']');
}
```

This should be slightly but perceivably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified demonstration of getting the results of your ajax requests into a variable that is available to your map function:

```js
var locations = []; //global variable array

$(document).ready(function() {
  var cell1 = "a1";
  var cell2 = "b1";
  var cell3 = "c1";
  var cell4 = "d1";
  //run each successive ajax function in the 'done' function of the previous
  $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell1 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result1) {
    $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell2 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result2) {
      $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell3 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result3) {
        $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1-LBh3AdwWxhvlkxZrsCuJSz9y4xuBT5DRCgHC_m6F6g&single=true&gid=0&range=" + cell4 + "&b6&output=csv").done(function(result4) {
          locations.push(result1 + ', ' + result2 + ', ' + result3 + ', ' + result4); //in the last function, push the results to the `locations` array;
          //call the map function
          goMap();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

function goMap() {
  //here's the result of your ajax requests to the spreadsheet.  You can use them in your map function.

  $('#locations').html('[' + locations + ']');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="locations"></div>
```

Comment: Much more readable to have the first and end part of the URL stored as constants. Is there any reason why you can't send all 4 ajax requests in parallel?

Comment: You can run them in parallel, but you need to wait until they have all completed before pushing the data to the array.

Comment: Well then you shouldn't be running them in sequence. If each request takes say 2 seconds on average, your code will add the four locations to the map after approx 8 seconds. If you ran them in parallel you're able to add them after the slowest request comes back, which shouldn't be much more than 2 seconds.

Comment: If you look at the OP's original code, you will see that each map location requires 4 AJAX calls - yes, it's not efficient and there are much better ways to do it, but that was not the point of the question - which was directed simply to getting the returned AJAX data into the location array.  To do this, with the current set up of the spreadsheet, you need to wait for all 4 requests to complete, and then concatenate the elements to create a location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without writing code, check out [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com).  It's an add-on for Google Spreadsheets that allows you to create an map directly from your spreadsheet and embed it on your website.  Check out the [advanced docs](https://geosheets.com/docs/advanced) for details on how to make the popup work using data from a column in the spreadsheet.